# What do you call snow that has collected between a car body and the tire?

Tags: single-word-requests

Snowy areas commonly see snow collect between a car body and tire. There is some strange satisfaction in kicking that snow off of the car and I've been in many conversations about miscellaneous details of this particular type of snow collection. Photographic example:

[image: Snow under tire.]

But is there a word I can use to refer to this clump? I am looking for a word similar to "icicle" or "stalactite" but a bit more specific.

Comment: It's called 'snow' regardless of its location.

Comment: A heap of snow?

Comment: fender's snowball?

Comment: *Agglomeration* ([1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/agglomeration),[2](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agglomeration#Noun)) isn't specific but might be appropriate

Comment: @whoabackoff: Perhaps you don't live in a snowy region but we have plenty of words for specific types of snow where I live.

Comment: What MrHen said...that dirty stuff behind the tire is no more "snow" than dog pee is "water" - both being thoroughly adulterated from their original forms.

Comment: @mrhen I live in the 2nd snowiest capital in the world. We don't have "plenty of words" for snow here based on it's location. Roof snow, road snow, snow on the steps, snow on my hat. It's all called 'snow' here. Feel free to share your abundance of snow location terms, though.

Comment: @whoabackoff, maybe it's just a lack of colorful vocabulary since obviously we can call everything that floated down from the clouds as stemmed ice crystals, "snow", but you have to admit that you don't call slush "snow slush", do you?  It's just slush. . .for one example.

Comment: @kristina perhaps you live in a different region than I do, but no one here calls dog pee "water". Everyone here calls "snow" "snow", though. If one was to mix the two, it is generally referred to as "yellow snow", please avoid eating the yellow snow.

Comment: @whoabackoff, that's exactly my point - thanks for helping me make it! ;-)  (and yes, stay away from the yellow snow!)

Comment: When I moved to Minnesota I soon found out that those are "slush puppies".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a [renowned authority](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142453/how-widespread-are-snow-goblins),  in the Northeastern part of the United States accumulations as shown are called *snow goblins*.  [Other authorities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142453/how-widespread-are-snow-goblins) call them  *snow cuds* or  *snow boogers*.

Answer (score 4):

I just posted [my own question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/292301?noredirect=1) about the term we use. I can't believe I missed your question! In New England (in Maine anyway), we call these *snow goblins*.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a very fun answer, but if you're in this situation—already talking about all this snow—you could call it "**buildup**" or "**wheel well buildup**".

This strikes me as the type of lingo mechanics use when they say something like, "You've got residue buildup in your cylinder head" or "there's a lot of corrosion buildup on your battery terminal. Better brush 'em off."

Comment: Yeah. That's build-up alright!

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this has any official acceptance, but in the US Midwest where it is snowy already, **"tire sludge"** would probably be understood.  I've already seen numerous chunks of tire sludge on the road and in driveways.

Comment: Yeah, "sludge" sounds relevant. Although I typically think of sludge as the crap left on the road after it was mashed up and mixed with dirt/mud. It's that nasty, brown, sloshy stuff.

Comment: @MrHen, yeah, I think of that stuff as sludge or just dirty slush.  I think you need the word "chunk" in there to get the picture.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the word to describe the mixture of snow and dirt. This type of snow can be found in wheel wells, the sides of plowed roads, and in parking lots (please note that this snow may be found in an abundance of locations not limited to the ones listed here)

This type of snow is called **Snirt**.

### Etymology 1

Blend of *snow* and *dirt*

### Noun

**snirt** (uncountable)

1. (US) Snow that is dirty, often seen by the side of roads and parking lots that have been plowed.

[wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snirt)

[official snirt website](http://snirt.com/)

Comment: so to be more specific "fender snirt"?

Comment: A relative of snirt is snice -- snow and ice thrown by the snow plow into a wall at the bottom of one's driveway.

Comment: And that explains "snow booger" in the answer above.

Comment: And it's one of 50 catalogued words describing types of snow. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_snow#On_the_ground

Answer (score 2):

My husband generally calls them *clunkers*, while I refer to them as *goobers*. 
This usage is common in Northern Indiana, but may not be common elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

We are from Buffalo and my husband calls them clunkers. Because of the noise they make when they fall up the tire.

Answer (score 1):

When I visited Minnesota, they were referred to as "crudsicles".  I do not know if the spelling was "crudsicle" or "crudcicle".  I assume that the word was derived from "crud" + "icicle", not "crud" + "cycle".

Answer (score 0):

In Minnesota, this build-up is sometimes called a *Shark tooth*.